# How do the 'Steeves' work? How do I tell which 'Steeve' is mine?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

One of the perks in *Deep Rock Galactic* is '[Beast Master](https://deeprockgalactic.gamepedia.com/Beast_Master)'. It allows you to:

> Charm a Glyphid Grunt to become your loyal companion. You can only have one tamed Grunt at a time. (5-minute cooldown)

The Grunts can be tamed by 'petting' them. The tamed Grunts are named 'Steeve' in-game. If other Dwarves also using the Beast Master perk tame the same Grunt type, it can get confusing because all the Steeves will look identical. Given the above:

- How do I tell which Steeve is mine?
- Is there a way to tell if my Steeve is still alive, especially if there are multiple Steeves running around after a fight (so that I'll know when I need to tame another Grunt)?
- Apparently, I can 'pet' an already tamed Grunt. This can get confusing if there are multiple identical Steeves in the vicinity. What does petting an already tamed Grunt do? Will petting another Dwarf's Steeve make that Steeve mine?
- What happens to the old Steeve if I tame a new one? Does it become hostile again?

[image: screenshot of multiple Steeves]

Answer (score 3):

> How do I tell which Steeve is mine?

Its AI will make him in general follow you while out of combat. So run other direction - Steeve should shortly follow, given enough distance.

In combat they will seek enemies, often going a big distance to another dwarf to protect him.

Tip: always try to tame stronger bugs (slasher and guard, see [wiki](https://deeprockgalactic.gamepedia.com/Creatures)) for coolness! They look cooler and are somewhat stronger (subjectively, never bothered to test it).

> Is there a way to tell if my Steeve is still alive, especially if there are multiple Steeves running around after a fight (so that I'll know when I need to tame another Grunt)?

Apparently it doesn't matter. Steeve doesn't last long.

Just use your skill by cooldown on next bug to make minus one enemy. Kill another with charge pickaxe skill. Then back to destroying bugs in a classic way - with weapons.

> Apparently, I can 'pet' an already tamed Grunt. This can get confusing if there are multiple identical Steeves in the vicinity. What does petting an already tamed Grunt do? Will petting another Dwarf's Steeve make that Steeve mine?

Petting does nothing, it's only for laugh. Petting may prevent you from using items (e.g. Molly), which is somewhat annoying at times.

Petting other dwarves Steeves is considered a crime. Be ready to take all consequences: angry dwarf and his angry friends may decide to shoot your down. If you are "petter" (that pervert type of dwarf who must pet pets of others), then do it when no one seeing you (during Dreadnaught fights is the best).

> What happens to the old Steeve if I tame a new one? Does it become hostile again?

Then the old Steeve is gone. His soul will go to a better place and he will not be forgotten.. at least until you charm roughly ~100500 other Steeves, because it's proven to be impossible to remember that many at once.

Answer (score 0):

if you tame a steve with friends and have multiple you can go away from the main battle and fight a single glyphid grunt and that MIGHT help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).